# How to resize logo in Rundeck?

Tags: image, resize, rundeck

I've my Rundeck server showing up a nice logo in the first log-on page. The issue is that is not possible to resize the image to something more small.

I found in internet these values:

```
rundeck.gui.logo-width = 68
rundeck.gui.logo-heigh = 31
```

But in version 3.3.1 this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are not referenced in the [documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/gui-customization.html#gui-customization). The last reference was in Rundeck [3.0.4](https://docs.rundeck.com/3.0.4/administration/configuration/gui-customization.html). Maybe the best approach, in this case, is to use a smaller image.

Comment: Tried that but is resizing by default seems to 300x300 or some specific size.